# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 32-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to connect Oracle DB using cx_oracle in pycharm IDE .
But am getting error while executing following code

Coding :

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('#####/******@1#####/#####')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from gl_user')
for result in cur:
   print (result)
cur.close()
con.close()
```

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError Error :DPI-1047 32-bit Oracle Client library cannot be "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for helploaded

Answer (score 1):

Follow the cx_Oracle [installation guide](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows). You need 32-bit Oracle client libraries installed - as shown by the DPI-1047 error. In particular, make sure you have PATH set correctly to include the Oracle client libraries (you may need to restart terminals or program, or at worst case reboot).  If you are using Oracle Instant Client, then make sure you have the required VC Redistributable, shown on the [download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html).